# nested json pass in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

I have to pass nested JSON through AJAX and the sample request should be in this format:

```
{
  'user': {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
  }
}
```

```js
login(){
        var email=document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
        var user_details={
            'email':email,
            'password':password
        }

       var myString=JSON.stringify(user_details);
        var param="{'user':"+user_details+"}";
        //console.log(param);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/newuser',
            data:param,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (argument) {
                console.log(user_details);

            }
        })
```

But this throws an error. 
Also I tried doing this

```
var user_details={
            'email':email,
            'password':password
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/newuser',
            data:JSON.stringify({'user':user_details}),
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (argument) {
                console.log(user_details);

            }
        })
```

But this is also of no use.I keep getting Internal server error.
The server side code for the same as of now is:

```
app.post('/newuser', function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    var obj=JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(obj);
```

What should I do?

Comment: What dose the error message say?

Comment: internal server error @Endless

Answer (score 2):

Your first code sample most likely throws an error as you're attempting to append an Object to a string, which will result in a completely different output than you require.

Instead, you can just pass the entire object to jQuery and it will serialise it for you. Try this:

```
function login() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/newuser',
    data: { 
      user: {
        'email': $('#username').val(),
        'password': $('#password').val()
      } 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(argument) {
      console.log(argument); // note use 'argument' here to get the returned data
    }
  });
});
```

If this still results in an error, then the error must lay with your server side code. You should check the response and/or the error logs to determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: does jquery allow you to pass nested json through data?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Note that that would have nothing to do with jQuery, it's the JSON standard.

Comment: @Rory may be you have to stringfy the json

Comment: @azad nope, jQuery does that for you

Comment: with this also I am getting errors @RoryMcCrossan.There is nothing in thebackend yet.

Comment: What are the errors? As I mentioned in the answer, at this stage there is nothing wrong with the JS code - at least not with what you've shown. Please check the console to find out the error response to aid with diagnosing the problem

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'application/json',`  to the `$.ajax` options object